# Nodejs express res.redirect loop

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, redirect-loop

Using Nodejs and an Express server I'm trying to prevent anyone from reaching my second set of routes without logging in and while this works I get stuck in a redirect loop if the session doesn't detect the email in the session token.  I believe its trying to check for the req.session.email for the /users endpoint as well causing the redirect loop but as the session checking middleware is used after I thought the /users endpoints would avoid the check.

How can I organize my code so that the books endpoints can only be reached when the req.session.email is satisfied and also not get stuck in a redirect loop when someone tries to reach it without being logged in?

```
app.use('/users', users)
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.session.email){
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
  else{
    next();
  }
})
app.use('/books', books);
```

Answer (score 2):

The order of the `app.use` statements is not really important in this case; You could add your middleware to the route-level if you're only checking the `/books` endpoint.

```
const yourMiddlewareFunction = (req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.session.email){
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
  else{
    next();
  }
}

app.use('/books', yourMiddlewareFunction, books);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to protect the `/books` endpoints, you can do it like this :

```
function requireLogin(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.session.email){
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
  else{
    next();
  }
}


app.use('/books', requireLogin, books);
```

Comment: sorry, didn't see another answer :)